# ng class not responding to class property change

Tags: angular, event-handling

I'm learning angular going through  [these vidoes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0eWrpsCLMJQ&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwhBRAgFinJR8KHIrCdTkZcZ), and trying out simple stuff.

I created a H2 tag using **ngClass** and set it with **ClassChooser** object.
 I created also an event handler to a button click, that changes the property **class1IsOn** value which **classChooser.class1** is assigned to, but ngClass doesn't respond to the change.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-test',
      template: `
                <h2 [ngClass]="classChooser"> class chooser result</h2>
                <button (click)="onClick()" > nadav </button>
                     `,
      styles:[`.class1{
        color: darksalmon;
      }.class2{
        font-style: italic;
       }`]
    })
    export class TestComponent implements OnInit {


      public class1IsOn = false;
      public class2IsOn = true;


      public onClick(){
        this.class1IsOn = true;
      }

      public classChooser = {
        "class1":this.class1IsOn,
        "class2":this.class2IsOn
      }
      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

It's strange your code. You can use

```
<h2 [ngClass]="{'class1':class1IsOn,
                'class2':class2IsOn"> 
     class chooser result
</h2>
public onClick(){
      this.class1IsOn = !this.class1IsOn;
      this.class2IsOn = !this.class2IsOn;
}
```

Or

```
<h2 [ngClass]="myclass"> 
     class chooser result
</h2>
public onClick(){
  this.myclass=this.myclass=="class1"? "class1":"class2"
}
```

Comment: what do you mean strange? I'm not asking about the style of coding, I'm asking why it's not working..

Comment: @nadavgam, when you write [ngClass]="something", "something" is an expresion that must be evaluated. But you want to equal to an expexion that must be evaluated first time, and then re-evaluated in the tag. I supouse that it's the reason beause don't work